# how to manually change record in heroku database

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a rails app hosted in heroku. I have a Questions table with a content column. The content column contains the word of a question. So for example if you queried. Question.first.content, you would get "Hello, how are you?". I have 8 questions in total. I would like to manually go into the database and change these questions.

I tried running the terminal on heroku with this command:

```
heroku pg:psql
```

and I used this query to change the content column of a record

```
UPDATE Questions
SET content="What country does this story orginate? (Japan)"
```

However I get this error message:

> ERROR:  column "What country does this story orginate? (Japan)" does not exist 
>   LINE 2: SET content="What country does this story orginate? (Japan)"...

What is the right query of changing the question's content column?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: Or you can you rails console - heroku run rails c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I can do `heroku run console`. Once in the console I can do active record queries such as `Question.find(1).update_attributes(:content=>'how are you?')` and it updates. For whatever reason `heroku run rails console` did not update the record with active record queries but just returned that the query was successful.

Answer (score 2):

SQL uses single quotes for string literals and double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names), that's why you're getting a complaint about an unknown column. The fix is simple, use single quotes for the string literal:

```
update questions set content = '...' where ...
```

Some databases let you use double quotes for strings but that's non-standard and should be avoided.